# Nested MySQL query on the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing many people and their full details.
if a certain man has a relation to another, than on his record there will be the other person ID under a cell called relation_to (a man can relate only to one other person)

I'd like to query the DB for all the men from california and list the people relating to them right under them.

```
select * 
from people
where sex='M' AND city='California'
```

this will result with the list of people I want to check who is related to them
now I'd like to upgrade this query to show under each result the people that have the person's ID on the 'relation_to' field.

How do I do that?

Comment: You meant you need a query to show hierarchy/hierarchies?

Comment: Yes, only one below from the main query results. not a recursive one..

Comment: can you give an example with dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it works for you. 
and please let me know about the results.

```
SELECT * FROM people
Inner JOIN people as p 
ON people.relation_to = p.id
where sex='M' AND city='California';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to JOIN a table to itself. This is allowed and easily accomplished using aliases.

```
SELECT * FROM people
JOIN people as relation ON people.relation_to = relation.id
where sex='M' AND city='California';
```

Comment: I dont think thats what OP meant!